# How do I detect text in natural images using OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In a project I have recently undertaken, I want to detect individual blocks of text in an image and put rectangles around them like in the image [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Thar.jpg)

I have tried various methods with openCV like pixel dilation and making a rectangle around the smallest area with most pixels, but to sub-par results with natural images (they worked fine when just a sheet of black and white paper)

I'd just like to know other people's methods, and what worked and what didn't to try and improve my code.

Comment: Look into Optical Character Recognition (OCR). Adobe has a really good tool for this.